# How to bypass a running process running and pass to the next code block in python?

Tags: python-2.7, unix, terminal, vlc, python-multiprocessing

So, i have a python program which has to start vlc by subprocess.call method (like: subprocess.call(['vlc']) ), Now this code rung Vlc and the execution of my python program halt's until i close the vlc player. So what i wanted to ask is there anyway through which i can start vlc and leave it running and my python code also moves to the next step without halting and waiting for the vlc player to close?
(BTW: i use a ubuntu 12.04 & python version 2.7)

I have tried using pass statement but it didn't work:

```
subprocess.call(['vlc'])
pass
<next code block in python>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i found a solution to this by using:

```
import subprocess #importing the module
subprocess.Popen('vlc') #This works
```